# Validate price value in order to insert into sales table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with one of the inputs like this:

```
<input name="price" type="text" />
```

I validate it so that I can insert into the database. The requirement I would like to have is:

- only number is allowed.
- if it's empty, the value will be 0 (zero) in be inserted into the **sales** table.

**1)** Validation step like this:

```
// Validate price:
if (empty($_POST['price'])){
    $price = 0;
} elseif(!empty($_POST['price'])) {
    $price = is_decimal($_POST['price']);
} else {
    $price = TRUE;
}
```

**2)** query to insert the price into the sales table:

```
$q ="INSERT INTO sales (price) VALUES ('$price')";
```

After running the query with the EMPTY value for the $price variable , I checked the sales table and found that the value that is inserted into the price column is 1.00, but not 0.00 as per my expectation.

What did I do wrong? And can you help? Thanks

**Notes:**

This is the function called *is_decimal*:

```
function is_decimal ($price){
   $price = trim($price);
   $price = preg_match('/^(\d)(.\d)?$/', $price);
   $price = round($price, 2);
return $price;
}
```

`Sales` table:

```
$query = 'CREATE TABLE sales (
        sale_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        price decimal(6,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (sale_id),
        ) ENGINE = MYISAM';
```

Comment: You could just do a cast: `$price = (float) 0;`. I don't know what you're doing with the `$price = true;` (which is both `else` results); `true` evaluates to `1` when coerced. Pay more attention to your logic flow.

Comment: Jared is correct. you should probably try to cast your result. by the time it gets around to going into the database currently, `$price` has a value of `TRUE` .  `TRUE` equals `1`

Comment: Why are you enclosing `$price` in `'` in the `INSERT`? That makes it a string, not quite sure mysql really likes that. Anyway, you should avoid interpolating variables in SQL code. Use mysqli or PDO with prepared statement and bound parameters.

Comment: @jcaron - There is, of course, [a man page for that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html).

Comment: @Jared. Thanks, and I dont use (float), but (int) because the table column is defined as decimal(6,2). And I replace TRUE with isset($_POST['price']) for my specific case. It work fine to me now. Again, thanks alot

Comment: @jcaron: i use single quote for _$price_ because I want it to be a string in the table **price** column. without it, it returns an error!

Comment: @nq_p, well, it's not a string! So if it returns an error, there really is something rotten in your code...

Comment: @jcaron:when i try testing it by entering _123.45_ instead of this _$price_ variable, it DOES insert into the table without any error as you said, and it MUST be true, because **integer** NEVER needs quote. However, when I erase the quote, it returns an error saying: _"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..."_. So, using quote is correct. More references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353345/inserting-integer-value-into-mysql-int-using-insert and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your function, specifically `preg_match`. You receive `1` because that is how many matches it found. To fix you can simply add a result variable to output to:

```
function is_decimal ($price){
        $price = trim($price);
        preg_match('/^(\d)(.\d)?$/', $price, $result);
        $price = round($result, 2);
return $price;
}
```

Comment: This is, of course, part of the OP's mangled logic, but having an `is_` function return anything other than a boolean is contra-indicative. It is entirely possible the *actual* logical flaw is how the `if` block was constructed, not this function per se.

Comment: Agree with the prey_match issue, but `is_decimal` is not supposed to be called in the "empty" case...

Comment: Have a look at the [example here](http://ideone.com/8Oa8dV), it should give you a clear idea of what is happening. Also depending on your php you might need to use `$result[0]` for the match variable as it's an array.

Comment: @jcaron, I just noticed what you mentioned with the empty call not using `is_decimal`; and as you and Jared both pointed out, it appears there's more than one bug in the code.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Totally agree with the thinking there - multiple issues at hand. I usually stay clear of the SQL stuff, but errors with regex I can spot pretty quickly. :)

Comment: I generally do not leave answers for code that only partially works, as it's not fair to others who may come along with a similar issue and end up with only one part of a solution. @OP, If you're unable to respond in a timely manner this answer will be deleted.